# Ubuntu dp dual monitors over usb-c are mirrored

Tags: multiple-monitors, laptop, intel-graphics, displayport, usb-c

I have Ubuntu 19.04 (not relevant, I tried it with ubuntu 18.04 and it didn't help). In windows this setup works fine, so it's not hardware or adapter issue...
I have Intel Graphics.

I'm trying to connect 2 screens to my laptop with usb-c adapter (that support dual monitor setup). the external screens are mirrored and appears as only one screen in the settings.

xrandr output:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3840 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192
eDP-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 309mm x 174mm
   1920x1080     60.05*+  60.01    59.97    59.96    59.93  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1600x900      59.99    59.94    59.95    59.82  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1400x900      59.96    59.88  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1440x810      60.00    59.97  
   1368x768      59.88    59.85  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1280x800      59.99    59.97    59.81    59.91  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    59.74  
   1024x768      60.04    60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.05  
   896x672       60.01  
   1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82  
   960x600       59.93    60.00  
   960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82  
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       60.01    59.88  
   864x486       59.92    59.57  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       59.98  
   800x450       59.95    59.82  
   640x512       60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   700x450       59.96    59.88  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x405       59.51    58.99  
   684x384       59.88    59.85  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   640x400       59.88    59.98  
   576x432       60.06  
   640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32  
   512x384       60.00  
   512x288       60.00    59.92  
   480x270       59.63    59.82  
   400x300       60.32    56.34  
   432x243       59.92    59.57  
   320x240       60.05  
   360x202       59.51    59.13  
   320x180       59.84    59.32  
DP-1 connected 1920x1080+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 476mm x 268mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  60.00    59.94  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   640x480       75.00    60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Also, this is system issue and not the desktop-env (gnome)
but there is my ~/.config/monitors.xml file contents

```
<monitors version="2">
  <configuration>
    <logicalmonitor>
      <x>3840</x>
      <y>0</y>
      <scale>1</scale>
      <monitor>
        <monitorspec>
          <connector>DP-1</connector>
          <vendor>DEL</vendor>
          <product>DELL E2218HN</product>
          <serial>33G588BSDD6I</serial>
        </monitorspec>
        <mode>
          <width>1920</width>
          <height>1080</height>
          <rate>60</rate>
        </mode>
      </monitor>
    </logicalmonitor>
    <logicalmonitor>
      <x>0</x>
      <y>0</y>
      <scale>1</scale>
      <primary>yes</primary>
      <monitor>
        <monitorspec>
          <connector>eDP-1</connector>
          <vendor>AUO</vendor>
          <product>0x303d</product>
          <serial>0x00000000</serial>
        </monitorspec>
        <mode>
          <width>1920</width>
          <height>1080</height>
          <rate>60.049468994140625</rate>
        </mode>
      </monitor>
    </logicalmonitor>
    <logicalmonitor>
      <x>1920</x>
      <y>0</y>
      <scale>1</scale>
      <monitor>
        <monitorspec>
          <connector>DP-2</connector>
          <vendor>DEL</vendor>
          <product>DELL E2218HN</product>
          <serial>33G588BSC0AI</serial>
        </monitorspec>
        <mode>
          <width>1920</width>
          <height>1080</height>
          <rate>60</rate>
        </mode>
      </monitor>
    </logicalmonitor>
  </configuration>
  <configuration>
    <logicalmonitor>
      <x>1920</x>
      <y>0</y>
      <scale>1</scale>
      <monitor>
        <monitorspec>
          <connector>DP-1</connector>
          <vendor>DEL</vendor>
          <product>DELL E2218HN</product>
          <serial>33G588BSC0AI</serial>
        </monitorspec>
        <mode>
          <width>1920</width>
          <height>1080</height>
          <rate>59.940700531005859</rate>
        </mode>
      </monitor>
    </logicalmonitor>
    <logicalmonitor>
      <x>0</x>
      <y>0</y>
      <scale>1</scale>
      <primary>yes</primary>
      <monitor>
        <monitorspec>
          <connector>eDP-1</connector>
          <vendor>AUO</vendor>
          <product>0x303d</product>
          <serial>0x00000000</serial>
        </monitorspec>
        <mode>
          <width>1920</width>
          <height>1080</height>
          <rate>60.049972534179688</rate>
        </mode>
      </monitor>
    </logicalmonitor>
  </configuration>
</monitors>
```

Comment: Are you sure that two individual outputs are supported in your configuration? I ask this because I own a USB C docking station with 3 display connectors (DP,HDMI,D-SUB), but the latter two share the same internal DP connection so I can only have individual outputs when one monitor is connected to DP.

Comment: Extending the screens is working in Windows with the same setup. I have docking station with three inputs (2xHDMI, 1xVGA), and all the combinations works in Windows but not in my Ubuntu...